# Stochastic Gradient Descent for Linear Regression on partial derivatives

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gradient-descent

I am implementing stochastic gradient descent for linear regression manually by considering the partial derivatives (df/dm) and (df/db)

The objective is we have to randomly select the w0(weights) and then converge them.
As this is stochastic we have to take the sample of the data set on each run

Learning rate initially it should be 1 and after every run it should get reduced by 2
so when wK+1 is equal to wK (k=1,2,3,......) then the loop should stop

This is implemented on the boston dataset in Sklearn

As I am new to python didn't use functions
Below is the code:

```
r= 1
m_deriv = 0
b_deriv = 0
learning_rate = 1
it = 1
w0_random = np.random.rand(13)
w0 = np.asmatrix(w0_random).T
b = np.random.rand()
b0 = np.random.rand()
while True:
    df_sample = bos.sample(100)

    price = df_sample['price']

    price = np.asmatrix(price)

    xi = np.asmatrix(df_sample.drop('price',axis=1))

    N = len(xi)

    for i in range(N):
   # -2x * (y-(mx +b))     
        m_deriv += np.dot(-2*xi[i].T , (price[:,i] - np.dot(xi[i] , w0_random) + b))

    # -2(y - (mx + b))
        b_deriv += -2*(price[:,i] - (np.dot(xi[i] , w0_random) + b))

    w0_new = m_deriv * learning_rate
    b0_new = b_deriv * learning_rate
    w1 = w0 - w0_new
    b1 = b0 - b0_new

    it += 1
    if (w0==w1).all():
        break
    else:
        w0 = w1
        b0 = b1
        learning_rate = learning_rate/2
```

and when the loop runs I am getting large values for w as well as b. They are not converging properly
where did the loop go wrong so its resulting in higher values and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In the above case, using `StandardScaler` before processing on `xi` gives good results and use `w1` instead of `w0_random`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
X = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)
Y = bos['PRICE']
df_sample =X[:100]
price =Y[:100]
xi_1=[]
price_1=[]
N = len(df_sample)
for j in range(N):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(df_sample) 
    xtrs = scaler.transform(df_sample)
    xi_1.append(xtrs)
    yi=np.asmatrix(price)
    price_1.append(yi)
#print(price_1)
#print(xi_1)
xi=xi_1   
price=price_1
r= 1
m_deriv = 0
b_deriv = 0
learning_rate = 1
it = 1
w0_random = np.random.rand(13)
w0 = np.asmatrix(w0_random).T
b = np.random.rand()
b0 = np.random.rand() 
while True:
   for i in range(N):
       # -2x * (y-(mx +b))
       w1=w0
       b1=b0
       m_deriv = np.dot(-2*xi[i].T , (price[i] - np.dot(xi[i] , w1) + b1))
       # -2(y - (mx + b))
       b_deriv = -2*(price[i] - (np.dot(xi[i] , w1) + b1))
   w0_new = m_deriv * learning_rate
   b0_new = b_deriv * learning_rate
   w1 = w0 - w0_new
   b1 = b0 - b0_new
   it += 1
   if (w0==w1).all():
       break
   else:
       w0 = w1
       b0 = b1
       learning_rate = learning_rate/2
print("m_deriv=",m_deriv)
print("b_driv",b_deriv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the `w` coefficients after each iteration. In your inner loop you are always using `w0_random` while you should be using the updated weights `w1` in your case. You will need to store the updated values `w1` after each iteration in a way that they can be used in the next iteration to calculate the derivatives.

I would also suggest to normalize your data to have `mean=0` and `std=1` so that you avoid large numbers.

The algorithm converges mainly because the learning rate becomes very small after some iterations and therefore `w1==w0-learing_rate*diff*derivative` by default. It doeas not converge because it found a solution in its current form.

Comment: Thanks for the help even though I changed w0_random to w0 I am getting higher values.

Comment: The fact that the weights are getting higher is not wrong. What you want to minimize is the cost function. Of course, if you haven't normalized your features and target your weights can grow big and become unstable. I think also by deceasing your learning rate so quickly you do not leave time to learn. instead of checking `w0==w1` in the end you should allow for a small precision deviation.